# How to set Dynamic position of Toast to a View?

Tags: android, events, checkbox, toast

First of all this is not complete code

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
    {
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0); 
        View view=toast.getView();
        switch(buttonView.getId())
        {
            case R.id.chkRed: if(chkRed.isChecked())
            {   
                              chkGreen.setChecked(false);
                              chkBlue.setChecked(false);
                              chkYellow.setChecked(false);
                              toast.setText("You Selected Red");
                                toast.setGravity(Gravity.NO_GRAVITY,buttonView.getRight(), chkRed.getTop());
                             //top does not align
                             //it align perfectly to right of checkbox
                              view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
                             break;
}
}
```

So now the problem is that I want to display toast beside checkbox, I tried working with `setGravity()`, but it just does not workup and have been hit and trying for long time, but with no progress

How to display toast beside the checkbox?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ok, i finally figured out how to get toast beside checkbox or another view

**1.** You need to get location on screen of the view, by

```
buttonView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
```

for more Reference, see [getLocationOnScreen(int[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29)

**2.** Set gravity to toast using

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT,buttonView.getRight()+5, 
location[1]-10);
```

the important thing here is set `x-coordinate` of toast to right of view, 
  e.g., `buttonView.getRight()` and get y-coordinate from the `location[1]` ,which you get from `getLocationOnScreen()`

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
    {
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0); 
        View view=toast.getView();
        int location[]=new int[2];
        buttonView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        switch(buttonView.getId())
        {
            case R.id.chkRed: if(chkRed.isChecked())
            {   
                              chkGreen.setChecked(false);
                              chkBlue.setChecked(false);
                              chkYellow.setChecked(false);
                              toast.setText("You Selected Red");
                              toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT,buttonView.getRight()+5, location[1]-10);
                              view.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
                              view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21026866/630833, takes size of Toast into consideration, which was helpful to me.